# D.C. Voltage gain

Tags: gain

How may I determine the D.C. Voltage gain in the circuit shown here:

[image]

> Figure P10.106 shows an amplifier formed by
>   cascading two CS stages. Note that the input bias voltage
>   is not shown. Each of Q1 and Q2 is operated at an overdrive voltage of 0.2 V, and VA = 10 V. The transistor capacitances are as follows: Cgs = 20 fF, Cgd = 5 fF, and Cd b = 5 fF. The signal-source resistance Rsig = 10 k.
>
> (a) Find the dc voltage gain.
>
> (b) Use the method of open-circuit time constants to determine an estimate for the 3-dB frequency fH .

I know that:

\$V_{dd}-V_o=i_o*r_o,
i_o+i=0.1mA,
i=k*0.2^2\$

I also know that \$r_o=V_A/i\$

From these equations I can get that:

\$V_o=V_{dd}-10-1/i\$

But how may I find \$i\$, the current through the transistors?

\$i_o+i=0.1mA=V_{g2}/r_o+i\$

Also,

\$V_{g2}-V_o-V_{tp}=-0.2\$, I think. But at this point I'm stuck as I don't know the threshold voltage.
Is anyone willing to please comment?

Comment: 1) I do not like how Q2 is drawn, Q1 is obviously an NMOS but Q2 has no arrow. It is probably an NMOS as well so Q2 is a source follower. 2) step 1 is determining DC currents. That's easy here as there are 2 DC **current sources** determining this. So the threshold voltage is **irrelevant**. 3) draw the small signal equivalent circuit. You're stuck a bit too much on voltage loops and solving them. Forget about solving them. The small signal circuit is what is important. From that you'll see that determining the gain is actually quite simple (assuming Q1 is in saturation).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Q2 is PMOS

Comment: I also don't like how Q1 is biased. If I choose the DC value of Vsig wrong then Q1 can be in triode mode making the gain calculation more complex. It would have been better to DC-bias the gate of Q1 with a high value resistor from it's drain and couple in the AC component of Vsig via a capacitor. Then at least we know Q1 is in saturation.

Comment: Q2 PMOS: OK then for small signal it will be the same as Q1 (common source). Then the same problem of Q1 (saturation or not) pops up for Q2.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it is D.C. Gain I am asked to find

Comment: Well, the DC gain varies over operating conditions of the MOSFETs (triode more vs saturation). Just as an exercise put the circuit into a simulator and plot Vo as a function of Vsig and you'll see that the gain is not constant. The gain is only reasonably constant in a small region of Vsig. In that small region the small signal equivalent circuit is valid and that's the normal way we determine gain for such a circuit. Asking for "the DC gain" means that whoever made this assignment missed some things.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it's from Sedra, I am quite certain of that. You may also find it here (p.155 in pdf file or 804 in document, q. 10.106):  http://www.personal.psu.edu/ahy5028/EE/EE310/Microelectronic%20Circuits/Problems.pdf

Comment: So how may I proceed with finding the DC voltage gain?

Comment: Gain is gm*ro its biased with a current source, so its fair to say its simplified schematic without biasing

Comment: @sstobbe yet the question specifically asks for DC voltage gain

Comment: @peripatein, yes open-circuit your capacitors

Comment: @sstobbe I'm not sure I understand. Is Vo simply gm*ro*Vdd in this case?

Comment: Gain is a ratio, i.e. Vo/Vi the DC-gain is just low frequency gain where you can ignore all capacitors. The value of Vo is the DC-operating point (or Quiescent Point) which is not what you asked.

Comment: @sstobbe but if I calculate standard small signal gain in what way are the current sources to be taken into account? Why are they needed?

Comment: Your CS amplifier needs drain current to operate, you will see in time in your studys that a current source is an active load and for the case of an ideal current source it has an ro=inf so r0,Q1 || ro,source = ro,Q1

Comment: I don't understand your problem with this question. We know \$I_{D1}\$,\$I_{D2}\$,\$V_{ov}\$ \$V_A\$. Hence \$g_{m1} = g_{m2} = \frac{2 I_D}{V_{ov}} = \frac{0.2mA}{0.2V} = 1mS\$ and \$ro1 = ro2 = \frac{10V}{0.1mA} = 100kΩ\$. And the voltage gain is \$10k \; V/V\$